# Проблемы с заполнением таблицы sqlite3

Tags: python, aiogram, sqlite3

Делаю телеграмм бота, создал таблицу и заполняю ее переменными вот код:

```
 def Fill_Database(con, cur, message: types.Message):
     cur.execute(f"""INSERT INTO user_info(id_column, weight_column, height_column, age_column,       gender_column) VALUES ({message.from_user.id}, {WEIGHT}, {HEIGHT}, {AGE}, {GENDER})""")
     con.commit()
```

Выдает ошибку:

> File "C:\Users\serbi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\handler.py", line 117, in notify
> response = await handler_obj.handler(*args, **partial_data)
>
> File "C:\Users\serbi\PycharmProjects\pythonProject2\CalculatorCcal.py", line 91, in calc_lifestyl
> await Fill_Database(con, cur, message)
>
> File "C:\Users\serbi\PycharmProjects\pythonProject2\CalculatorCcal.py", line 109, in Fill_Database
> cur.execute(f"""INSERT INTO user_info(id_column, weight_column, height_column, age_column, gender_column) VALUES ({message.from_user.id}, {WEIGHT}, {HEIGHT}, {AGE}, {GENDER})""")
>
> sqlite3.OperationalError: no such column: woman

То есть как я понял проблема с заполнением столбца `Gender`.

Comment: Использовать Format при выполнении запросов - небезопасно. Потом исправьте это

Comment: Также для решения вопроса, могли бы предоставить проект таблицы user_info и примеры того, что находится в {WEIGHT}, {HEIGHT}, {AGE}, {GENDER} при ошибке

Comment: Хотя в-принципе я понял в чем ошибка

Answer (score 1):

Начнем с того, что писать запрос без параметров - это **плохо**

Ваш параметр **GENDER** - это строка. В SQL строка должна быть обернута в `'`

То есть выглядеть так в вашем случае: `'{GENDER}'`

Чтобы не задумываться о безопасности запроса и о типах передаваемых параметров в litesql можно передавать их таким образом:

```
execute(Запрос, (параметры,) )
```

Там, где необходимо подставить параметры пишем `?`. Параметры передаем по порядку `?` в запросе

То есть в вашем случае:

```
cur.execute("""INSERT INTO user_info(id_column, weight_column, height_column, age_column, gender_column) 
VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)""" , (message.from_user.id, WEIGHT, HEIGHT, AGE, GENDER,) )
```